# Pass value in text if second option selected

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to create a survey. The code looks like this:

```
<form ng-submit="passEngineer(engineer)">
    <input type="radio" ng-model="engineer" ng-required="!engineer">Default
    <input type="radio" ng-model="engineer" ng-required="!engineer">Custom
    <input type="text" ng-model="engineer" ng-required="!engineer">
</form>
```

If `First` selected, it DOES pass it without issues. If `Second` selected, it SHOULD pass the value entered inside `third` input. How can I do that? Value in third input MUST be passed if second input selected. Tried many ways, can't really figure out.

Comment: I think your problem is that you have the same value applied to three different `ng-model`s

Comment: That's exactly correct. Can you give us a better idea of what you want?

Comment: @sthames42. I want to pass first input value if Default selected. If second second input selected, then it must pass the value entered in the third input value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to divide up how you're applying `ng-model`. You might make `engineer` an object in your controller and then change your markup like this:

```
 <form ng-submit="passEngineer(engineer)">
    <input name="engineer" type="radio" ng-model="engineer.isDefault">Default
    <input name="engineer" type="radio" ng-model="engineer.isCustom">Custom
   <input type="text" ng-model="engineer.customValue" ng-required="engineer.isCustom">
 </form>
```

Comment: Ah, good call. I edited my code. You've gotta give them the same name to make them mutually exclusive.

Comment: Still makes me able to select both values.

Comment: Do you have your ng-model stuff set up? Here's a fiddle of it working sans-angular stuff: https://jsfiddle.net/soxd7nda/